# How to subset a pandas data-frame based on a dictionary using case-insensitive matching

Tags: python, dictionary, string-comparison, case-insensitive

I have a dataframe which contains various products and their descriptions as shown in the image below:

[image]

I have a dict which contains the key-value pairs based on which the filtering has to be done:

ent_dict

```
{'brand': 'Dexter', 'color': 'brown', 'product': 'footwear', 'size': '32'}
```

As can be seen the dict and dataframe might contain values in different cases and hence I need to do case-insensitive matching here. Also there might be columns that are numeric for which normal matching will do.
So can someone please help me in this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The above works for string matches. You can further change the final statement to match the integers too.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import re

df = pd.DataFrame({'Product': np.array(['Footwear' for i in range(4)]), 'Category': np.array(['Women' for i in range(4)]), 'Size': np.array([7, 7, 7, 8]), 'Color': np.array(['black', 'brown', 'blue', 'black'])})

ent_dict = {'Category': 'Women', 'Color': 'black', 'Product': 'Footwear'}
values = [i for i in ent_dict.values()]
columns = [df.filter(regex=re.compile(i, re.IGNORECASE)).columns[0] for i in ent_dict]

df[eval(" & ".join(["(df['{0}'] == {1})".format(col, repr(cond)) 
            for col, cond in zip(columns, values)]))]
```

The case insensitive search can be accomplished using `str.contains` of `DataFrame` object.

```
df[eval(" & ".join(["(df['{0}'].str.contains({1}, case=False))".format(col, repr(cond)) 
            for col, cond in zip(columns, values)]))]
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response but the problem is that in my df the value for color might be "Black" but in the ent_dict it is 'black'. This does not work in that case.

Comment: thanks a lot @praba230890 for the help.One last thing,if I put size also in the checking part I get a typeerror. I am not sure how to do string matching with integers in python 3+ as in Python 2.7 it was allowed.